# What database structure is suitable for tracking File audits?

Tags: sql, file-systems, audit

I need to track permissions and access requests to a file server in a database.  I'm given the full path of the folder and am considering parsing the path (splitting on the "/" character) and creating a self-referential link to the table... in addition to a column intended to store the full file path.

What is the ideal approach for dealing with such a system that can have a tree of folders and having a database schema suited for that purpose?

Is self-referential columns overkill?

Comment: `Is self-referential columns overkill?` -- That's what you have to do if you want to support a tree-like data structure (folders within folders).

Comment: Although... http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Comment: @RobertHarvey The image in that linked post gives me ideas.  What if instead of numbering the nodes algebraically, I wonder if other math could be applied (fractals, Elliptical Curves, etc) to define the relationship between entities with even more properties.  Would you rule out (or rule in) any such property?

Comment: That kinda depends on your use case, I think.  For a file tree, I personally would just go with something more orthodox, like self-referential foreign keys.

Comment: @makerofthings7 if you want to go down the path of relationships, the preorder tree is a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).  There's nothing saying you can have *multiple* sets a given node belongs to.  The preorder tree is an approach to get around the lack of hierarchal relationships in some databases without a significant read penalty.

Comment: Oh, I'm inferring that since hierarchical relationships exist in some databases... it may exist in MSFT SQL?  I'll look into it

Comment: SQL has HiearchyID ... this may be something I can use  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4048190/328397